# What trim l should I use for to transition to quarter round?

Tags: baseboard

[image]I’m installing 5-1/2” baseboards throughout the house except at the base of cabinets/vanities, where I’m doing quarter round.  When I come around this corner post (picture) from the living room, however, I’m encountering a tricky configuration that I hope y’all can help me with.  As you can see, if I wrap all the way around this corner the trim is higher than the cabinet into which it runs, and will impeded the cabinet door from opening.  Should I end the baseboard at the face, & change to quarter round around the corner?  If so, what’s the classiest way to do this?  Other suggestions?  Any and all are welcomed.  Thanks[image]

Comment: How much of a gap is there between the wall and the cabinet door?

Comment: I would cut a notch out of the top corner of the little wall trim, bottom ~half goes all the way to the cabinet kickboard, to allow the door to open, then chamfer the vertical edge to make it look more natural.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  Jack, the gap is 5/8” but when it opens there’s about a 1/4” of play outwards, meaning it’s hit the 3/4” baseboard.  Dandavis the problem I’m having with a notch is that when the cabinet door swings wide, it’ll likely still hit the baseboard.  Ive considered a notch on the outer side but that may look stupid.

Comment: Run a 3½" piece from the cabinet into the full height base. Then have your quarter round at the toe kick. Easy money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think keeping it simple would be best. I would end the baseboard on the end of the wall at the beginning of the radius and then transition to the quarter round around the radius and back to the kick space. The width of the quarter round will be more than the thickness of the baseboard, and as such, you will need to cut off the excess. I would try this first and see how it looks.
[image]

I would create a mockup first of the three pieces, gluing them together with Cyanoacrylate (CA) glue and activator.

You may need to touch-up the wall above the quarter round with some spackle.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a piece of 3½" trim from the cabinet to the full height trim and then just run your quarter round at the toe kick.

You'll have to prime that end cut good before painting, but, after everything is caulked and painted it'll look just fine.

Comment: I don't think that will work as the cabinet door gap appears narrower than the thickness of the trim.  Unless the trim is shorter than the toe kick (unclear from the photo perspectives).

Comment: @Huesmann Re-read the answer. The 3½" trim will go from the toe kick to the corner where the  full height trim is. It would be underneath the door and wouldn't affect it at all.

Comment: OK that's true, but then you have a 2" height difference at the corner, which will look pretty meh.

Comment: @Huesmann Not necessarily, once caulked and painted it likely won't be that noticeable. We'll just have to agree to disagree. Have a great day.